# VBA Run-Time Error 1004: Range(" ").Formula Code

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

When executing the below code, I receive the Run-Time Error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error". I'm not sure what is causing the error. I use the below Range.Formula code often and have never had this issue. I've confirmed the sheet name, range, and formula are all correct. The formula works when pasted into the excel sheet. What exactly am I missing?

```
Sheets("PORTFOLIO PRESENTATION").Select
Range("K20").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP('PORTFOLIO PRESENTATION'$A20,$S$20:$T$270,2,FALSE),"")"
```

Comment: you need to change the `""` to `""""`

Comment: Hi Scott - Like so? Range("K20").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP('PORTFOLIO PRESENTATION'$A20,$S$20:$T$270,2,FALSE),"""")" ? I'm still receiving the same run-time error.

Comment: You are also missing the `!` after the sheet name in the formula.

Comment: You don't need the sheets name in the formula, as you are putting this formula in the same worksheet

Comment: Taking the sheet name out and inserting the """" fixed it. Thank you both for your help! Corrected formula is : Range("K20").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A20,$S$20:$T$270,2,FALSE),"""")"